# 2 linux partitions, how to force one's grub menu to win?

Tags: grub2, kernel, updates, mbr

I have 2 Ubuntu partitions

- Ubuntu 14.04 that is my desktop system
- Kubuntu 14.04 that is my development enviroment

Each time Ubuntu 14.04 updates the kernel, writes his own grub menu, and each time Kubuntu 14.04 updates the kernel, writes his own grub menu

When Kubuntu 14.04 has written his own grub menu, how can I force Ubuntu 14.04 to gain again control of the grub menu (and I suppose of the MBR)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot back into Ubuntu and run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

this will reconfigure grub based on the partition where you are,
after this you could run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and it will update the menu defaulting to itself.

Comment: Was the first thing I tried, but doesn't seems to work. The menu doesn't change

Comment: @nulll, ahh right, if you don't have a shared /boot partition, then you will also need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` to reinstall grub to your mbr and point it at the ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 2):

If I well understood you, you don't want Kubuntu to install GRUB. You may uninstall GRUB on Kubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove grub-pc
```

Comment: Of course that means that when Kubuntu gets an updated kernel grub won't start using it.

Comment: Yes, but Ubuntu will also get kernel update at the same time.